# TestCafe oncePerFixture Error when running

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to use oncePerFixture feature in TestCafe and get an error:

“TypeError: Cannot read property “testRun” of undefined.

I cannot figute out what is the problem?

Comment: My code: import EventAPI from '../../Commons/API/AdminEventPortalApiUtils';
import { oncePerFixture } from 'testcafe-once-hook';
const cleanDB = oncePerFixture(async t => {
   if (!TcUtils.isProduction()) {
      await EventAPI.deleteQaTestEvents();
   }
});
fixture `Clubs - Club Home Page`
   ...
   .afterEach(async t => {
      if (!TcUtils.isProduction()) {
         cleanDB();
      }
   });

Comment: From Page Model
async deleteQaTestEvents() {
   if (TcUtils.isProduction()) {
      throw Error('ERROR: ClubApiUtil should NOT be used in production.');
   }

   let results = await this.findEventByTag('qatestevent');
   for(let i = 0 ; i < results.data.length; i++){
      const clubDeleteResponse = await this.deleteEventById(results.data[i].id);
      await t.expect(clubDeleteResponse.status).eql(200);
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the problem is that you forgot to pass the `t` argument to the `cleanDB` function call inside the `afterEach` hook. If this does not help, please share your full example, as it's difficult to determine the cause of the issue without your full code.